# What is the difference between process value and electrical value?

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

I have an inductive sensor which measures the movement of a plunger. The plunger feeds with fuel an internal combustion engine. There is an interface where it is shown the movement of the plunger in mm and also I can read process value and electrical value.

What is the difference between these two terms?  What is process value?

Sorry for the naive question, engineer here

Comment: Is this built into a fuel injector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An electrical value shall represent a measurement in electrical units, like volts, amperes, ohms, henries, farads,...

A process value is a value usually used in control loop. This may have physical units (mm in your case) or even without it. It's a common practice to use normalized values \$V^*=\dfrac{V_{input}}{V_{max}}\$ it would be 0.0 if Vin=0V and 1.0 (100%) if Vin=Vmax, without physical units.